# ip command is missing from ubuntu docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu

when i'm trying to perform ip command in ubuntu docker container, i'm getting:

> bash: ip: command not found.

ubuntu version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

what package should i install for that command?

Thanks

Answer (score 167):

You could use `apt-file search` to determine the command in which package. From my ubuntu16.04, it tells me to install `iproute2`, I think 1804 similar.

**1. Get what package need to be installed:**

```
$ apt-file search --regexp 'bin/ip$'
iproute2: /bin/ip
iproute2: /sbin/ip
```

**2. Install the package:**

```
$ apt install -y iproute2
...
```

**3. Verify the package is installed:**

```
$ dpkg -l iproute2
ii  iproute2    4.3.0-1ubuntu3      amd64      networking and traffic control tools
```

Comment: But to use `apt-file` you first need to install and update its cache:  `$ apt-get install apt-file` then: `$ apt-file update`

Comment: `Unable to locate package iproute2` on `apt install -y iproute2 `.
`apt-get update` needed first. See here: https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/installing-iproute2-on-ubuntu20-04.html

Comment: $ apt-get install apt-file was the missing piece for me.

Answer (score 66):

Don't forget to install the iproute2

```
apt install iproute2
```

And then you may use `ip` command.

Comment: Do you mean from inside the container ? How would I do that if there's no network to download anything ?

Comment: This process assumes you have Internet connection I have no idea how to do it without connection.

Comment: On ubuntu 18 host and guest.  I have working connection on host, I have masquerade set in iptables, I have bridge docker0 set up all automatically. apt update in container is not working, ip, ping, route, ifconfig commands are missing, /etc/network/interfaces file is missing.

Comment: Not necessary. We can execute `chroot rootfs_dir` and then apt install `iproute2`. @Pavel Niedoba

Comment: This is only a subset of the existing answer posted one year before and does not bring any new information.

Answer (score -3):

**I hope it could help:**

```
root@458517c8d93f:/# ip a
bash: ip: command not found
root@458517c8d93f:/# ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found

root@458517c8d93f:/etc/systemd/network# apt-get install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  net-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 194 kB of archives.
After this operation, 803 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 net-tools amd64 1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1 [194 kB]
Fetched 194 kB in 3s (69.0 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package net-tools.
(Reading database ... 9962 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../net-tools_1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking net-tools (1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up net-tools (1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1) ...
root@458517c8d93f:/etc/systemd/network# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.4  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe12:4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:ac:12:00:04  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21578  bytes 54216887 (54.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19156  bytes 1057383 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536    
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 2100 (2.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 2100 (2.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: This still does not answer the question and answer below is already correct. You are demoing that you can install `ifconfig` but NOT `ip`.

Answer (score -8):

Once you have created your docker with ubuntu latest or any of version image and crated a ubuntu container, you have to run your ubuntu container and install the following for the basic networking command,

```
apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

apt-get install -y net-tools

apt-get update
```

Comment: This is not correct. ip is not part of net-tools

Comment: @LukeBriner I hope the next comment will help